# Codename One: I want to implement Automatic reading functionality

Tags: android, sms, codenameone

I want to implement Automatic OTP reading functionality in My project which I have built using Codename One.

I have implemented this functionality in core Android and I want to implement it using Native Android code in Codename one.

Where do I add below Receiver code in codename one?

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.IncomingSms">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Where do I add "IncomingSms" class in codename one native code?

How do I call this native methods in main codename one code while receiving message?

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a blog post about intercepting incoming [SMS messages](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-intercept-incoming-sms-on-android.html).

Diamond wrapped that code in a [cn1lib](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-activation-ui-builder-pattern.html) too.

Comment: To get the library: right-click on your project -> Codename One -> Codename One Settings -> 3rd party Extensions -> Search for `SMSInterceptor` -> download -> Refresh cn1lib or clean build.